# Place all of the available emails for a person on 1 row - Pivot?

Tags: sql-server

One table

```
ID     Name     Email
101    George   Georges1stEmail@hotmail.com
201    Fred     Freds1stEmail@hotmail.com
301    Sally    Sallys1stEmail@hotmail.com
101    George   Georges2ndEmail@hotmail.com
101    George   Georges3rdEmail@hotmail.com
301    Sally    Sallys2ndEmail@hotmail.com
101    George   Georges4thEmail@hotmail.com
101    George   Georges5thEmail@hotmail.com
```

For the example below, I can't get the Email4 and Email5 fields to fit on this code page, but I'd like to either create another table that looks like this (with the addition of the Email4 and Email5):

```
ID   Name     Email1                       Email2                       Email3      
101  George   Georges1stEmail@hotmail.com  Georges2ndEmail@hotmail.com  Georges3rdEmail@hotmail.com
201  Fred     Freds1stEmail@hotmail.com    
301  Sally    Sallys1stEmail@hotmail.com   Sallys2ndEmail@hotmail.com
```

There can be a total of up to 5 emails for one ID.

Please and Thanks!

Comment: Have you searched for SQL rows to columns?

Comment: If you're using SQL Server 2008, it's really past time that you upgrade; it's been completely unsupported for a year now.

Comment: Yes, the results point to many different Pivot threads.  But I am not clear on it.  I tried to make the post as descriptive of my needs as I could.

Comment: So what *have* you tried? Why do you want to swap from a normalised dataset to a denormalised one?

Comment: The goal is to place all of the available emails for a person on 1 record instead of many records.  There can be up to 5 emails per person.  I don't know how to do it, so I tried asking the question on this forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everyone needs a little nudge from time-to-time.

If you have a known or maximum number of emails, you can perform a `PIVOT` in concert with the window function `row_number()`

**Example**

```
Select *
 From  (
        Select ID
              ,Name
              ,EMail
              ,Item = 'Email'+left(row_number() over (partition by id order by  email),2)
         From YourTable
       ) src
 Pivot (max(EMail) for Item in ([EMail1],[EMail2],[EMail3],[EMail4],[EMail5]) ) pvt
```

**Returns**

[image]

Or you can perform a Conditional Aggregration

**Example**

```
Select ID
      ,Name
      ,EMail1 = max(case when RN=1 then EMail else '' end)
      ,EMail2 = max(case when RN=2 then EMail else '' end)
      ,EMail3 = max(case when RN=3 then EMail else '' end)
      ,EMail4 = max(case when RN=4 then EMail else '' end)
      ,EMail5 = max(case when RN=5 then EMail else '' end)
 From  (
        Select *
              ,RN = row_number() over (partition by id order by  email)
         From @YourTable
       ) src
 Group By ID,Name
```

**Returns**

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much John, I will give this a shot.

Comment: @caddy Always happy to help.  Note the second option using a conditional aggregation will provide empty strings instead of NULL values

Comment: Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Done!  I had tried to upvote but it wouldn't let me,  :)